# displaying table from database in a web page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html

How to fetch data from MySQL database based on the input given in a web page and display the content in the same webpage without reloading using PHP or any other relevant language. Could anyone help me with a sample code?

Comment: Can you show that you've at least tried to do this yourself?

Comment: You need to do an Ajax request, google it.

Comment: Can Ajax be used to fetch data from the database? or is it just used for updating without reloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a lot of concepts in one question.
First you need to look into mysqli documentation are see how to make queries to your needs here http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
To update content from page based on queries from your database I would sugest you look into Ajax documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
If you run into problems with the code post it here but just after you do your research on the matter.

Comment: Thank you. How to fetch data from MySQL database based on the input given in a web page and display the content in the same webpage? No need for automatic updating. Could you please help me with a sample code.